# How do I update to the latest version of `serve`

Tags: npm, node-modules, gatsby

I am using Gatsby v1.1.52 running Node v8.11.3.

When I run `gatsby serve` I am prompted with with message mentioning that there is an `UPDATE AVAILABLE: The latest version of`serve`is 9.1.0`. I've tried running `npm update -g gatsby' and 'npm update -g gatsby-cli`.

[image: Update available message]

I can't find any documentation: the manual entry does not exist, the options (`gatsby ?`) doesn't include an update command and `gatsby serve ?` only serves the website again.

[image: Gatsby options]

I found a global npm package called serve but it is on version 5.6.0 and I don't think it is the same package that is being referred to in this instance but I am grasping at straws here.

Any ideas what command I need to run in order to update `serve`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`gatsby`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby) comes with `serve@^6.5.3` installed, so there's not much you can do except wait (or open a PR!) until it's updated in the `gatsby` package. Fortunately there's not really a need to update it since it still works fine, it's just a notice from `serve`.

Answer (score 17):

For those not using Gatsby, here is how to update serve:

Globally: `sudo npm update -g serve`

Locally: `npm update serve`

Comment: You don't need sudo to install globally. You could very well do `npm update -g serve`

Answer (score 6):

Run the following via terminal:
`sudo npm i serve@latest -g -d`

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

```
yarn upgrade -g serve
```